# 'JASMINE_BROWSER' is not recognized as an internal or external command when running client side unit test on meteor angular app

Tags: meteor, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-meteor

I am trying to setup velocity/jasmine environment for running angular-meteor app.I have added the following packages: urigo:angular, angular:angular-mocks, sanjo:jasmine, and velocity:html-reporter. The tests are running fine but I get Chrome popup by karma every time tests run, which I want to avoid.

I tried `JASMINE_BROWSER=PhantomJS meteor run`, following the tutorial http://farla.io/2015/05/11/unittesting-angular-meteor.html, but I keep getting the error:

`'JASMINE_BROWSER' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things. First, you have not said if you are using Linux Mac or Windows. See, things change between platforms. Since I used Windows, I'll assume that :P

Also, you didn't say which versions of Meteor, sanjo:jasmine, Karma (...) you are using. See, things change between versions, too :) I'll assume you are using: meteor 1.1.0.3 and sanjo:jasmine 0.17 (and Karma pulled automatically by sj:0.17) - since I noticed the same problems on that combination.

I recently battled with that, you can read [details here](http://quetzalcoatl-pl.blogspot.com/2015/08/sanjojasmine-prevent-meteor-from.html).

In short - let's start from windows that popup: By default, when using Chrome as runner target, on Windows there are actually two popups: console with nodejs and window with Chrome. You'd like to get rid of both. From what I checked, hiding nodejs console window [requires a small change to code to meteor/long-running-child-process](https://github.com/Sanjo/meteor-long-running-child-process/pull/8)(that's patch #1). Then, you can "hide" Chrome by adding some commandline params that tell it to move far away from the screen area, that requires a small update to Karma's configuration that sanjo:jasmine generates - [see this patch](https://github.com/Sanjo/meteor-jasmine/pull/269)(that's patch #2). I use these two changes on Windows and it works quite nice. Until these patches mature and sanjo decides to use them, the only way of using them is downloading the code from github, merging those patches, and using that local sanjo:jasmine package instead of official one.

Of course, you may want to drop Chrome and get PhantomJS like anyone else says. If you run it, you won't see 'browser window' since PhantomJS doesn't show any. However, in this setup, once PhantomJS is selected and once it really works, you will still get the console from nodejs I mentioned above. And you can get rid of it with the patch #1 I mentioned above.

Last thing - you failed at running PhantomJS as the target, because most of the helpful advices are wrong. Currently (I mean, sanjo-jasmine:0.17/0.18) the correct way to select PhantomJS is:

```
JASMINE_BROWSER=PhantomJS
```

and just that. Not a word or dot more. It's because the text from that variable is matched strictly against these strings:

```
'Chrome'
'ChromeCanary'
'Firefox'
'PhantomJS'
'SauceLabs'
'HiddenChrome' (that one works ONLY if using the second patch I mentioned)
```

It's also worth noting that Karma supports using multiple targets at once (It can launch and use Chrome **and** PhantomJS at once), but sanjo:jasmine currently supports only one at time. Attempts like:

```
JASMINE_BROWSER=PhantomJS,Chrome
```

**currently will not work** (-> [see source of ClientUnitTestFramework](https://github.com/Sanjo/meteor-jasmine/blob/master/src/client/unit/ClientUnitTestFramework.js#L122-L131))

Comment: thanks a ton, answered all my questions/doubts to precision.